# Using DKMS in pi-gen

Tags: raspbian-buster, pi-gen

### The problem

I am attempting to build a DKMS based module in pi-gen and not having any luck finding `raspberrypi-kernel-headers`.

I am working in `stage3` of the pi-gen build.  I have the following steps

00-configure-apt where I add 2 private repositories to the public repositories initially added in stage0.

01-misc-config I add sudo without password capabilities to the default user.

02-install-hd44780-i2c (where the problem is).  This step has a single `00-packages` file containing:

```
raspberrypi-kernel-headers
dkms
udev
hd44780-i2c
```

Which is a bit of overkill since the fist 3 are declared in the 4th's dependency list anyway.

However the problem is that they system responds with:

```
DKMS: add completed.
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 5.4.0-58-generic cannot be found at
/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/build or /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/source.
dpkg: error processing package hd44780-i2c (--configure):
 installed hd44780-i2c package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Notes:

- I am running pi-gen in the standard pi-gen Docker image running on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
- `5.4.0-58-generic` is the version of the system running the build.
- `uname -n` in the scripts returns the build system kernel version.
- I know that the version I want (for this build) is "5.4.79+" and that if I execute `find / -name 5.4.79+ -type d` in a `run-chroot.sh` returns `/usr/lib/modules/` as the directory.  So executing `ls -1 /usr/lib/modules/ | head -1` will return a valid kernel version.
- I can find no other way to determine what kernel pi-gen is installing.

As an attempted fix I added `apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers` to `stage0/00-configure-apt/00-run.sh`.  The result was that the headers were pulled and installed.  However stage 3 can not see them.

After much messing about I added three packages as 00-packages

```
raspberrypi-kernel-headers
dkms
udev
```

I then discovered that the kernel being installed could be found in /usr/lib/modules in a run-chroot.sh script so I added 01-run-chroot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo $PWD
find / -name 5.4.79+ -type d

export kernelver=`ls -1 /usr/lib/modules/ | head -1`
export KERNELDIR=/usr/lib/modules/${kernelver}/build

export
```

The result does show that `kernelver` is being set as expected and KERNELDIR is set as well.

Finally I created a `02-packages` that contains the package to install

```
hd44780-i2c
```

I also attempted to add `apt install hd44780-i2c` to the `01-run-chroot.sh`, that yielded the same result.

The makefile for the `hd44780-i2c` package is:

```
VERSION=1.0.0

ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := hd44780-i2c.o
    hd44780-i2c := hd44780-i2c.o

else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    echo "START OF DEBUG"
    export
    echo "END OF DEBUG"
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

endif
```

And the latest output (noted above) appears to show that the *else* portion of the build Makefile is being executed

### What I think I need

I think that I need to be able to get the `KERNELDIR` variable set in the environment where dkms executes in.  But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Does anybody have a suggestion for how to resolve this issue?

As an aside, this seems to be a bit "wobbly" -- that is it doesn't smell right.  Is there a proper way to create a Debian install that uses `dkms` to install a kernel module and call that installer from `pi-gen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above the problem is to get the proper kernel version into the DKMS build.  I solved this by modifying pigen as well as the dkms call in the package being installed.

**PIGEN Changes**

in pigen/build.sh I added a function to capture the versions

```
check_kernel_version()
{
    if [ -z "${DKMS_VERSIONS}" ]
    then
        if [ 0 -lt `find ${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/src -name linux-headers\* -type d | wc -l` ]
        then
            for fn in `cat ${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/src/linux-headers*/include/config/kernel.release`
            do
                export DKMS_VERSIONS="${DKMS_VERSIONS} -k ${fn}"
            done
        fi
        log "====> Kernel Version: '${KERNEL_VERSION}'"
    fi
}
```

This function sets a `${DKMS_VERSIONS}` environment variable if it is not set and the linux-headers have been installed.  It adds all the kernel versions to the `DKMS_VERSIONS` variable as a series of `-k version` strings.

I modified the `run_sub_stage` function so that it calls `check_kernel_version` at the end of `${i}-packages-nr` and `${i}-packages` stages.  This picks up the versions as soon as the kernel headers are added.

**DKMS Project Changes**

in the `postinst` script for the dpgk installation of the DKMS based project add the DKMS_VERSIONS variable to the dkms commands.

```
        dkms build ${DKMS_VERSIONS} hd44780-i2c/1.0
        dkms autoinstall ${DKMS_VERSIONS}  hd44780-i2c/1.0
```

This then tells dkms to use the versions specified with the `-k` option rather than asking the system what kernel it is building on.